# Can't seem to get Wine to install "Package dependencies cannot be resolved"

Tags: 12.04, wine

Just built a new computer. Been using ubuntu for years now and was naturally what I put on the new box.

Tried to install Wine through the "Ubuntu Software Center" but got "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" in a window with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.3 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4.1) but 1.4-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4.1) but it is a virtual package
```

How do I fix this?

FWIW: I'm running ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit)

Any insight would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

"is to be installed" sounds like you might just need a reboot after the initial batch of apt-get updates...

in any case, I'd install wine1.5 (sudo apt-get install wine1.5 should do it), it's made some strides over the current stable branch.